# Powershell eliminate files with exact extension in -Exclude

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet

I used this cmdlet in my PowerShell script to get all files in the path except the rdl files :

```
Get-childitem $path -recurse -Exclude *.rdl | select -expand fullname
```

The problem is that the command also eliminates files with extension ".rdl.rss" and that's not what I want.

How can I eliminate only files with the exact extension ".rdl" ? Thanks Guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` rather than `-Exclude`:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.rdl'} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```